# Accessing WordPress Customize Panel values

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Here is the code I'm using to add the section to the Customize Panel.

```
function apple_customize_register($wp_customize){
    $wp_customize->add_section('apple_footer', array(
        'title'    => 'Footer',
        'priority' => 120,
    ));
    //------ display copyright in footer
    $wp_customize->add_setting('theme_options[copyright]', array(
        'capability' => 'edit_theme_options',
        'type'       => 'option',
    ));
    $wp_customize->add_control('theme_options[copyright]', array(
        'settings' => 'theme_options[copyright]',
        'label'    => __('Display Copyright'),
        'section'  => 'apple_footer',
        'type'     => 'checkbox',
        'value' => '1'
    ));
}
add_action('customize_register', 'apple_customize_register');
```

I have tried `get_option('theme_options[copyright]')`,  `get_theme_mod('theme_options[copyright]')` and many more, but all `var_dump` are returning `bool(false)`.
How do I use the values in my theme?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `[copyright]` is one of the values of an **Array**.
Get the theme options with `get_option('theme_options');` And inside the result you'll find `'copyright'`.

```
$options = get_option('theme_options');
echo $options['copyright'];
```

This is how you store a big number of options inside a single record in the database (the recommended way). If you visit the page `http://example.com/wp-admin/options.php`, you'll see all records in `wp_options` table. Some plugins and themes use one record per option, the result is not pretty.

If you add another control to the Customizer, register as `theme_options['OTHER_CUSTOM_SETTING']`. Remember to change *theme_options* for your theme's slug.